Is it possible to implement PDEs with 'pdepe' inside a simulink scheme?
I want to implement a model in simulink, but this model requires to solve a system of PDEs. How can I implement it knowing that in the equations there are parameters that varies according to time and space, since they depend on the variables on which i solve the PDEs?
By using MATLAB Function block, I can solve the PDEs using 'pdepe', but it requires a timespan and a spacevector upon which it solves the equations, but in this way the parameters used in the function are computed with the solutions at a particular time. Instead I want a solution of my variables in which the solutions at every (t,x) are coomputed using parameters that are updated every (t,x)
Let me know if you need more detailed information.
Thank you

You want to solve your PDEs without space discretization? And your PDE parameters are time and space dependent?
